# Grails GSP template rendering too slow

Tags: performance, grails, gsp

I'm currently using Grails 2.3.5.

I have a problem that my gsp rendering is too slow (almost 3 seconds even in production mode)

I have nothing exceptional in my controllers, simple queries and a form.

But I have many nested templates. I don't know if this could cause a problem.

Any idea on how to make the rendering faster, or is there a best practice to write GSP templates ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors?

Comment: No i printed the times on the controller and javascript, and the biggest difference is between when we call the render page in the controller and when the page starts rendering in the browser (the begining of document.ready)

Comment: Can you share the app, if feasible, for a sneak peak?

Comment: Do you have any loops? Are you calling a service in a loop? You could be opening and closing many transactions, which is very slow.

Comment: I had a similar issue but my pages were taking 10 seconds to render. I tracked down the culprit to be the `${g.message()}` tag when called in a taglib (by benchmarking). I ended up implementing a homebrew version of this tag that resulted in page rendering of less than 1 second.

Comment: try to identify the bogus template which may be having iterations and    work on that ...

Comment: In fact all my templates are slow, the more nested templates there is the slower it becomes, i can't put some code but all my grails application is ajax based. Any clue of what might be the problem ?

Comment: @nickdos thanks for the hint with `g.message`, had the same problem - after extracting g:message calls from a loop, a page with many items is orders of magnitude faster (Grails 2.4.2)